# Differences between models and theories

Tags: mathematical-modeling, applications

I'm trying to write about the differences between models and theories for academic writing (with no greek letters). I wonder if you agree with my text.

> The differences between theories and models are several:
>
> - Differences in representation
> - Differences in usage
> - Differences of    notation
>
> Theories are sets of statements that can be infinite and thus don’t
>   represent reality. A model, on the other hand, is a representation of
>   reality. A model is used to understand reality while theories are
>   about what is true and false. The model is used to understand the
>   theory.
>
> A theory could be a mathematical relationship for mechanics whereas
>   the term model is used for representing or approximating a theory.  In
>   this sense, the difference between a model and a theory is not always
>   large.

I can not find a source for that a theory can be infinite. Do you agree?

Comment: What have you got against Greek ? Its a beautiful language.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus The Professor rejected my attempt.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean, but if you want some really good advice from someone who has been around the block several times, you should stop caring what your professors think.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I write a Bachelor's project/thesis about symbolic model checking with the language SMV and the tool nuXmv. First i tried to write the formulas with many greek letters but we found that it was maybe easier to understand and not necessary to use anything else than plain English. My report was 40 pages first and we limited the scope to model checking. Now the professor thinks that I should also write something with citation to a paper about HOL4 which is slightly beyond the scope if I were to decide. I'm trying to please the professor because he is similar to a client.

Comment: Clients pay, your professor will give you NOTHING.

Comment: A model can also be infinite.

Answer (score 3):

You're correct that a theory is a set of statements, and that a theory can be infinite. However, the question of "reality" is an iffy one in logic - for example, models can *also* be infinite.

Theories can be thought of as "descriptions"; they list facts. A model is a structure - or, put a little more sensationally, a universe. A model is a thing *in which* facts can be true or false.

For example, the structure of the natural numbers with the usual operations $+$ and $\cdot$ are a *model*. The number $2$, for example, is in this model. The corresponding *theory* is the set of true things that can be said *about* this structure. $2$ is not in the theory, because it isn't a sentence. But the sentence "$2$ is prime" is in the theory, because it's a true fact. The sentence "$2$ is not prime" isn't in the theory, because it isn't true.

I've answered this under the assumption that the "logic" tag is accurate. Importantly, you may be talking about a *different* sort of "theory" and "model". For example, we can talk about the "theory of gravitation" and about a "model of population growth". These are *very* different from the concepts in logic, and you should make sure that you understand which one you're trying to write about.

Comment: Can our model be infinite because there are non-deterministic values if we don't put constraints on our model and don't assign boundary values? There is no tag "model checking" but that is the topic of my work. Do you agree that bounded and unbounded model checking is the same difference as finite and infinite?

Comment: @DjDac From that comment, it's clear to me that you're talking about models of physical processes in some sort of applied-math context, not theories and models in the sense of logic. That means two things: (a) The "logic" tag was incorrect, and I've now fixed that; and (b) what you're actually asking about is very, *very* far from my field of expertise. Good luck!